# Python: How to call a function that is in a module using a dictionary?

Tags: python, function, sockets, dictionary

I'm currently making my own module which includes some functions. In my main program I want to create a dictionary, which will hold all the functions in it and will execute one of them based on the user's input. 
The idea is to use the dictionary to call a function from the module using the user's input, but I haven't managed to do it yet.

```
def which_function(client_message, albums, songs):
    functions = {"0": report_error,
                 "1": return_albums,
                 "2": songs_in_album,
                 "3": length_of_song,
                 "4": lyrics_of_song,
                 "5": which_album,
                 "6": search_by_name,
                 "7": search_by_lyrics}
    function = functions[client_message[0]]
    return data.function(client_message[1], albums, songs)
```

This is the function that is supposed to execute each functions using the user's input (client_message[0]), but it's not working as intended...

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
functions = {"0": report_error,
NameError: name 'report_error' is not defined
```

Thank's for everybody's help :D

Comment: Where have you defined the functions? Where is `report_error`?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear enough. All the functions are defined in a module i created called "data". report_error is just another function i need for my task, :)

Comment: If you aren't importing that module in to the current file then it won't know that report_error is a funciton. How are you importing it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've imported the `data` module already. You need to use the imported functions inside the dictionary.

```
def which_function(client_message, albums, songs):
    functions = {"0": data.report_error,
                 "1": data.return_albums,
                 "2": data.songs_in_album,
                 "3": data.length_of_song,
                 "4": data.lyrics_of_song,
                 "5": data.which_album,
                 "6": data.search_by_name,
                 "7": data.search_by_lyrics}
    function = functions[client_message[0]]
    return function(client_message[1], albums, songs)
```

And in the end, you can invoke the value stored in the dictionary directly (no need for `data.function` - that won't work)